# Autosys job scheduled to run except last 4 days of every month

Tags: calendar, autosys

I was looking into scheduling an autosys job which runs on all workdays, but except last 4 days of every month. I use the autocal_asc command and do not use GUI.

I tried to set up the 3 calendars with MNTHD#L with adjust = 0; MNTHD#L with adjust = -1 and MNTHD#L with adjust = -2 for example. Wanted to include this as exclude_calendar option in my job definition. But exclude_calendar does not accept multiple calendars.

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved. You can use Standard Calendar instead of an Extended calendar.
Import the specific dates from a file into Calendar - The dates on which the job should not run. In this case - last 4 days of every month. And then you can use exclude calendar feature.

Let's say we have this file - last4daysOfMonth -

calendar:last_4_days_of_month

01/28/2015

01/29/2015

01/30/2015

01/31/2015

.

.

12/31/2015

You can create a Standard calendar by importing these dates using this autosys command -

> autocal_asc -I last4daysOfMonth

And in the job, you can specify this calendar as exclude calendar.

date_conditions:1

exclude_calendar:last_4_days_of_month

days_of_week:mo,tu,we,th,fr

start_times: 02:00

This will run the job on all weekdays except last 4 days of every month.

Answer (score 0):

Anotherway is to create an extended calendar with condition as

> **MNTHDM1|MNTHDM2|MNTHDM3|MNTHDM4**

this considers last 4 days of all months.

Add this calendar to

> exclude_calendar

attribute for your jobs.